# Trying to use WP_Query to return post with and without meta values

Tags: query

I am trying to return posts that contain meta value and ones that don't in one query.  Is this possible?

So in plain English, I am trying to get posts that have a meta key of date and value of date and posts that don't have date set as well.

This is what I have so far and it isn't working. UPDATED - i have now added another meta to the post to make it easier...I added no-date meta so instead of checking for it being empty, I am checking if no-date is set. So my revised code now looks like this but I can't seem to order it now.

```
 $args = array(
            'cat' => $type,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
                    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
            'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array('key' => 'date', 'value' => date('m-d-Y'), 'compare' => '>=', 'type' => 'char'),
                    array('key' => 'no-date', 'value' => '1', 'compare' => '=')
                    )

        );
```

So now this "seems" to return what i want...however I can't seem to sort it using orderby...I want the date to be closet first and future date last and for the no-dates ones to come after the ones with date via the post date.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You use both '**meta_key**' and '**meta_query**' - it is a wrong usage. Remove this code:

```
'meta_key' => 'date',
```

and try again.

After remove $cat WP produce sql query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.*
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id)
WHERE 1=1
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')
AND (
  (
    wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'date'
    AND CAST( wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) >= '03-17-2012'
  )
  OR (mt1.meta_key = 'no-date' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS CHAR) = '1' )
)
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY post_date desc
LIMIT 0, 10
```

If You have no results, check your data, because query is correct.

Comment: and I tried that before...without it, I can't set the orderby...according to the codex, meta_key must be set to have orderby...thanks for the reply though..

Comment: Please see updated code which "seems" to work now but I can't order it like I could if I did a simple one criteria.

Comment: What dou you have in "cat" param?